# Unable to prevent rerender with shouldComponentUpdate() or with PureComponent

Tags: reactjs, iframe, react-router, rerender

In `/home/:id` I have a `<LogButtons/>` when its clicked `logOn()` get called so `logsignPopUp` variable become a `<logForm/>` component.

In the same page I have a `<IframeYoutubeComponent/>`, I want to prevent it to rerender when the `<logForm/>` pop on the screen so the **video isn't reloaded**.

**home.js :**

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { logsign: "" };
        this.logOn = this.logOn.bind(this);
        this.signOn = this.signOn.bind(this);
    }

    logOn() {
        this.setState({ logsign: "log" });
    }

    render() {

        let logsignPopUp = this.props.logsign === "log" ? <LogForm/> : this.state.logsign;

        let homePage =
        <div>
            {logsignPopUp}
            <div>
                <LogButtons logOn={this.logOn}/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <IframeYoutubeComponent paramsId={this.props.match.params.paramsId}/>
            </div>
        </div>;

    return (
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/home/:id" component={() => <div>{homePage}</div> } />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**iframeYoutubeComponent.js :**

```
export class IframYoutubeComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        //this.props.youtube come from Redux state
        let src = this.props.youtube.find(el => el.youtubeId === this.props.paramsId);
            return (
                <iframe src={"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + src}></iframe>
            );
    }
}
```

I tried to return false in shouldComponentUpdate() but its not even called :

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
    console.log("test");
    return false;
}
```

I tried to use a PureComponent for `<IframeYoutubeComponent/>` but the video still reload when the `<logForm/>` pop.

I tried to add key to my components and also tried to put `this.state.logsign` in `Redux` but nothing worked out.

I started react since 2 months so I might miss something obvious but I can't find out what... Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are passing an arrow function in a `component` prop to the `Route`. This way everytime you generate a new function.

You should pass a react component in this prop or at least a function that returns JSX but this function should be defined once. For example as a class method.

Something like:

```
<div>
  <Route exact path="/home/:id" component={this.renderHomePage} />
</div>
```

But then of course you have to refactor your logic regarding this `logsign` prop.

Comment: I did create an homePage component instead of my homePage variable and the video in the Iframe component doesn't reload thats perfect ! I don't even need shouldComponentUpdate() or anything. Thanks a lot, you saved my day :)